# how to get json object in webview?

Tags: android

First, the webview activity shows Facebook Login.
If I login with my id, the server returns a json object that contains some information I need.

How can i get json object???

```
public class Activity_SNSLogin_Webview extends AppCompatActivity {

    Login_Utils util;
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity activity;
    private WebView webView;
    private String url;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        activity = this;
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        util = new Login_Utils(mContext, activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_Login);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String urlConnection){



            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

Comment: You must use `FacebookSDK` for Android.

Comment: All the work related facebook is in charge of the server.

Comment: Use facebook sdk to login to facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android